# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am tring to send mail by AWSCredentials but getting an exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory

I have added these jar:

- aws-java-sdk-1.3.11.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.3.11-javadoc.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.3.11-sources.jar
- aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.3.11.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- httpclient-4.0-alpha4.jar
- httpcore-4.0-alpha6.jar
- log4j-1.2.13.jar
- mail.jar

My java code is -

```
 import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SESExample {
public static final String ACCESS_KEY = "My Access";
public static final String SECRET_KEY = "My Secret";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sender = "support@brandzter.com"; // should be verified email

    LinkedList<String> recipients = new LinkedList<String>();
    recipients.add("khoyendra@globussoft.com"); // again a verified email, if you are in sandbox

    SendMail(sender, recipients, "Hi", "Hi how are u?");
}

public static void SendMail(String sender, LinkedList<String> recipients, String subject, String body) {
    Destination destination = new Destination(recipients);

    Content subjectContent = new Content(subject);
    Content bodyContent = new Content(body);
    Body msgBody = new Body(bodyContent);
    Message msg = new Message(subjectContent, msgBody);

    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest(sender, destination, msg);

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
    AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
    SendEmailResult result = sesClient.sendEmail(request);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

I am also trying to search this jar but not getting.
Am I using wrong jar not sure.
can any one tell me what is the problem?

I am

Comment: Can you show us the classpath's file ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory.html), the `SchemeSocketFactory` class is only available since version 4.1. So this might have something to do with the fact that you are using the 4.0 alpha jars. Try upgrading your http-client library to 4.1 or higher.

Comment: Now I am using httpclient-4.2.jar and getting new error.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext: method <init>()V not found

Comment: You need the [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi) jar in your classpath.

Comment: Yeah I have added these but still getting --- 

 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext: method <init>()V not found

Comment: You may also need to replace the http-core.jar to something higher than 4.0

Comment: If you download the latest aws java SDK (I just downloaded aws-java-sdk-1.9.3), the required libraries will be in the third-party/**/lib folders. There are a bunch of them! Currently I am finding the following httpcomponents jars:

httpclient-4.3.jar

httpcore-4.3.jar

Answer (score 2):

From [the javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory.html), it seems that the `org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory` class exists since the 4.1 version.

So, try to upgrade httpclient jar to at least 4.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the latest aws java SDK (I just downloaded aws-java-sdk-1.9.3),

> the required libraries will be in the third-party/**/lib folders. There are a bunch of them!

This answer from **jomofrodo** needs more atention. Nailed it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had two libraries that I created in Netbeans 7.2: one for the Apache Commons Codec 1.6, and one for the Apache Commons HttpClient 4.2.2. In this case, because the library I made for HttpClient also contained the Codec 1.6 jar, I was getting this same error.

Be sure you don't have two of the same libraries referenced in your class path, or two conflicting versions of the same library.

Answer (score -1):

debug your code and point out where Exception occur. Any of instance of class  that you used is not included  in your jar file i think so. am not sure. find that by debugging. i think SchemeSocketFactory is not exsisting in your class path. please check

Comment: error coming on this line - AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);

Comment: Any of class that you used in AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient is not in your class path. please check.......