# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V

Tags: java, spring, websphere, spring-ws

I'm trying to Set the **ConnectionTimeout** and **ReadTimeout** in the Spring **WebServiceTemplate** by using the HttpComponentsMessageSender. However, I'm getting **NoSuchMethodError** for the **SchemeSocketFactory** class.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender"
    id="timeoutId">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="3000" />
    <property name="readTimeout" value="3000" />
</bean>
```

---

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:96)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.<init>(HttpComponentsMessageSender.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: Could help [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151519/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-conn-scheme-schemesocketfactory)

Comment: What release and maintenance level of of websphere?

Comment: Version 8.5.5.7 (8.5.5007.20150820_2101)

Comment: Can it be done by using PARENT_LAST in the Deployment.xml so that I don't have to use the Shared Library?

Answer (score 2):

I think a fixpack upgrade will fix this for you.  WebSphere has an internal copy of the Apache HTTP client (used by its JAX-RS implementation) that was visible to installed applications until fixpack 8.5.5.9.  If you want to use your own copy on a fixpack prior to that, you'll need to utilize PARENT_LAST class loader delegation or an isolated shared library in order to make sure that the class loader loads your own copy of Apache HTTP instead of WebSphere's.

Comment: This did work but now I'm getting another exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory (initialization failure)

Comment: The "initialization failure" means that the class was found but failed in its static initialization.  Check to see if there's a stack trace with the "clinit" method of SSLSocketFactory in it - that would represent the class's static initializer.

Comment: Can it be done by using PARENT_LAST in the Deployment.xml so that I don't have to use the Shared Library?

Comment: PARENT_LAST would have the same basic effect. A shared library is slightly "safer" in the event that there's something in the app that would conflict with PARENT_LAST class loader delegation - a shared library would allow you to target the PARENT_LAST to only the APIs that needed it, rather than it applying to everything in the EAR/WAR.

Comment: With the Shared Library it's working fine. However I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider exception

Answer (score 0):

A *NoSuchMethodError* indicates that classes available at runtime are different to those used to compile your code.

It usually boils down to having multiple versions of the same class on the classpath. Double check this for the class in question and remove the unwanted version.